# Executing sudo commands without sudo keyword

Tags: linux

How can I enable that each user on a server will be able to execute a sudo command without specifying the sudo keyword - but not across all server, just a few chosen directories?

EDIT:
Just to make sure I understood things correctly, if I want to grant user `eliran` permissions to read, write and execute for some `DIR` i should execute `setfacl -m u:eliran:rwx DIR` ?

Comment: Meaning login as root. Then to restrict the root access to a few dirs will not be easy. Better to tell us why you want that (the context) and we might tell you what to do, instead.

Comment: @e2-e4 Would it be easier / more reasonable to enable all users to execute a sudo command without specifying a password in some chosen dirs?
For example, each user has an home directory and I wanted to give them a permission to create new directories under this one without specifying the sudo keyword

Comment: @EliranTurgeman Why would they need sudo to create new directories in their own home directory?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist That's the current situation i'm trying to fix, it is a new server.

Comment: @EliranTurgeman Unless there is something more to it than what you describe, there is no reason why sudo should be involved in that process. It rather sounds like ownership/permissions are somehow set incorrectly for these home directories? Is so, the solution ought to be to fix the incorrect ownership/permissions rather than to try to construct some really unusual sudo configuration as a workaround for what should be a non-sudo task.

Comment: The `sudo` command is intended to allow a user to run a command/program with a different security context then their own. Typically that different security context defaults to the “root” (super) user and administrator account although also other security contexts can be selected. Depending on what exactly you’re trying to achieve there are probably alternative solutions to either allow your normal user to achieve what they need without executing commands in a different security context or by using a different method to achieve that security context.

Comment: For instance with extended permissions you can design much more granular file and directory permissions than the classic UGO model allows. Other commands can be configured with policy kit to run as root without using sudo

Comment: So the problem might be that the user don't actually own their home directories? how would I fix that? 
I did execute `chown` on each user and matching home directory, shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: @EliranTurgeman: Did you use a **recursive** `chown` on every subdirectory as well? Option `-R`.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I enable that each user on a server will be able to execute a sudo command without specifying the sudo keyword

You do not say *which* "sudo command" you want these users to be able to run.  Knowing *that* might this discussion [a lot] more useful.

However, my question would be **why** do they need to use sudo *at all*?
This suggests to me little understanding of or, at best, scant regard for, the Unix security model.

> ... but not across all server, just a few chosen directories?

Anything run through **sudo** *without* explicitly specifying a username is run *as root* and, because of this, all bets are off.  The root user can do *anything*, *anywhere*.

This feels to me like an "X-Y Problem" - you *want* to get your failing Solution "X" to work, but what you actually *need* is a completely *different*, Solution "Y".

Describe your end goal in more detail and we may be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: I need that every user will have permissions to manipulate files and folders inside his home directory (create, delete, move, copy..) does this clarify my question a little?

Comment: They get those permissions by default.  
Or, at least, they should do.

Comment: Ok so for example how would I add these permissions to another directory? 
meaning that all users could manipulate files there

Comment: @Eliran Turgeman For example add these users to a group and own the directory by this group. Furthermore you can achieve complexe rules like inheritance on creation time of files/directories with setfacl.

Comment: Assuming that all users are under group `g` in order for the group to own a certain directory I just need to execute `chown g path/to/directory` ?
And then they will all have the permissions I specified before?

Comment: Make sure it's recursive like this: chown -R username:groupname directory. But remember: Files within this folder that are newly created don't inerhit this permissions/ownership, this set's only the ownership for existing files and subfolders. For new files to inherit you need to specify acl's with setfacl. Just lookup setfacl in the web.

Comment: @LukasRäpple could you please check the edit I made to the post? just wanted to be sure i'm doing it right